# Configure local kafka docker image to work as Azure EventHub

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, docker-compose, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to configure with docker-compose a Kafka to work as an Azure EventHub.
Here's the configuration used to connect to the EventHub with a node client :

```
new Kafka({
  clientId,
  ssl: true,
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'plain',
    username: '$ConnectionString',
    password: azureEventHubsEndpoint,
  },
  brokers: [
    `${broker}:9093`
  ],
  logLevel: logLevel.NOTHING
})
```

So I'm trying to configure a local Kafka to work as an Azure EventHub (with SASL PLAIN mechanism enabled) with this docker-compose but I got errors.

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: false
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT, SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka_server_jaas.conf
    volumes:
      - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
```

Here's the error received from the kafka container:

```
Failed authentication with /192.168.65.1 (Failing SASL authentication due to invalid receive size) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Could you please help me ?
Thanks